# Как сократить код? Только начал учить JS

Tags: javascript

```
function Switch1(){
  document.getElementById("img").src = "img/proj/1.png";
  document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "Прожект 1";
}
b1.onclick=Switch1;
function Switch2(){
  document.getElementById("img").src = "img/proj/2.png";
  document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "Прожект 2";
}
b2.onclick=Switch2;
```

Как это сократить? Мне кажется что как-то можно. Только начал изучать js, не судите строго.

Comment: если еще html разметку показать - то можно сократить даже то, что в ответе написал Igor

Comment: @СергейМишин, тут разметка на столько банальна, что ее можно и не показывать.

Answer (score 3):

```
function Switch(num, text){
  document.getElementById("img").src = "img/proj/" + num + ".png";
  document.getElementById("txt").innerText = text;
}
b1.onclick = function(e) { Switch(1, "Some text"); };
b2.onclick = function(e) { Switch(2, "Some other text"); };
```

Comment: Спасибо, но единственное - мне нужно там не прожект писать, а разный текст. Так-что этот вариант чуток не подходит.

Comment: @Scheuth, вам показали пример как вставлять в строку какое-либо значение, всё, что вам нужно, это добавить новый аргумент и при создании указывать папку

Comment: @Scheuth в целях оптимизации получение элемента из дома стоит вынести из функции

Answer (score 0):

Если подключить jQuery, то можно так:

```
for (i=1;i<n;i++){
  $('#b'+i).on(click, function(){
    $('#img').attr('src','img/proj/'+i+'.png');
    $('#txt').html('Прожект'+i);
  });
};
```

Этот вариант подойдёт, если у вас дальше будут подобные элементы с изменяемым индексом, где n - максимальное количество элементов.